# How to open picture from resources?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I use this code but it does not work. Picture does not open by default photo viewer

```
public static void OpenPicture(object source,EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap1 = AD.Properties.Resources.dust2;
    File.Open(bitmap1, FileMode.Open);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by _does not work_? Any exception or error message? It is impossible to answer the question with such a less information. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems you already got the `Bitmap` from resources, then Why do you want to open it again? Also, I'm pretty sure `File.Open` method doesn't takes a overload with `Bitmap`.

Comment: Picture from resources does not open by Windows Photo Viewer.I need show picture after run my program.( I am sorry for my bad English,I am High school student from Russia)

Comment: You can't. Unless you first write the image to a place Photo Viewer can find  and open it you can't make it show am  image from your resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got some misunderstanding.

First thing first, `Bitmap` is a class that encapsulate information for an image, but **not the image on the disk**. If you want a Windows Photo Viewer to open a picture, you need to store that image to somewhere on your disk, thus the Photo Viewer could find and open your picture.

Second, `File.Open` is a function for you to [open a `FileStream` on the specified path with read/write access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but not **running an external process to open a file**, like what you want to achieve.

To conclude, if you want your program to open a picture in Windows Photo Viewer, you need to

1. Save your bitmap information to a location;
2. Run Windows Photo Viewer in your program by using `Process.Start()` command.

Here is a simple example:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(AD.Properties.Resources.YourImage);
bitmap.Save("YourImageLocation");
Process.Start("YourIamgeLocation");
```

Some notes on choosing saving location is: never choose your system drive to avoid unexpected failure because of lack of write permission. A typical choice will be a subfolder under `ApplicationData`. Below is a demo with appropriate folder choosing:

```
// here you could replace "YourApplicationName" with any name you want, but
// name it after your application is a better convension
var destPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "YourApplicationName");
var picPath = Path.Combine(destPath, "pic.jpg");

if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
}

var bitmap = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.dust2);
bitmap.Save(picPath);
Process.Start(picPath);
```

Also remember to delete the temp picture after use, if this pic is not supposed to be saved.

Comment: Need i write full path for image in "YourImageLocation"?

Comment: i suggest you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Image.Save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more information about bitmap.Save() :)

Comment: My code looks like now:public static void OpenPicture(object source,EventArgs e)
        {
           
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(AD.Properties.Resources.dust2);
            bitmap.Save("C:\\dust2.bmp");
            Process.Start("C:\\dust2.bmp"); but it still doesn't work :((

Comment: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's error message did you get? this piece of code works fine on my computer.

Comment: Not error,just image doesn't open by photo viewer.

Comment: Sorry I gave a wrong example: you should not store information directly under "C:\\", try to store it on your desktop or some folder that you have **write permission**.

Comment: Maybe we continue our discussion in to the chat? Oh,no my reputation below 20, i can't use local chat.

Comment: I'm fine if we talk via email :)

Answer (score -2):

Add that image into your application's Resources Folder.
And then you can use:

```
var img = new Bitmap(Application_name.Properties.Resources.image_name);
```

Comment: And after my program run picture open by Windows Photo Viewer?

Comment: I use your code,but picture stil doesn't open.